# Extract data from string JS

Tags: javascript, string, variables, replace, extract

I'm trying to extrait data from a variable text on javascript

```
var text= "
    Data:
        data1 (str)
        data2 (int)
        data3 (str)
    TODO:todo
    "
```

result `var data = ["data1", "data2","data3"]` any idea?

Comment: You would need to parse the text string.  Alternatively, and probably a more efficient way, would be to use a json object to store the data, and then build the text off of that data.

Comment: other then custom parse or regexing it, if you tweaked it slightly its basically yaml, https://runkit.com/lcherone/5eea3e5bc6149a00138049ad which there's a package for, though json is always better

Answer (score 0):

You could use a forEach() loop

```
var data = ["data1", "data2","data3"];
var sentence = ''
data.forEach(el => {
  sentence += el + ' ';
  console.log(el); // each element separate
})

console.log(sentence) // each element as 1 sentence
```

Comment: thanks @JaySnel but i want the reverse sentence to  array data